# Why I can not @Override onDraw in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-intent, android-activity

I used Custom control from Toolbox and in create method

**View vw= findViewById(R.id.view1);**

I wrote this and below is my code, I don't know why I can not @Override the onDraw method like anonymous
class? When I tried to implement it says that super type is needed

```
      vw.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {


            float x = event.getX();
            float y = event.getY();

            switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                touchCircle_start(x, y);
                vw.performClick();
                vw.invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                touchCircle_move(x, y);
                vw.performClick();
                vw.invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                touchCircle_up();
                vw.performClick();
                vw.invalidate();
                break;

            }

            return true;

        }


        /******************************************************/

        private void touchCircle_start(float x, float y) {
         System.out.println("start");
         Paint paint=new Paint();
         Canvas canvas=new Canvas();

         canvas.drawLine(0, 0, 150, 150, paint);
         vw.draw(canvas);
        }

        private void touchCircle_move(float x, float y) {
            System.out.println("move");

        }

        void touchCircle_up() {
            System.out.println("up");
        }

        /******************************************************/


    });

}
```

Comment: What do you mean? I cannot find any `onDraw()` method in the code you provided. Please provide more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because onDraw() is method of View class, so you have to extends View Class in anonymous class.

Comment: Sagar, How can I do that? will you please elaborate it please? I dont want to take another class for that

Comment: Then you can create sub class in main class which extends Activity.

Comment: which extends activity or View?

Comment: MainClass extends Activity and SubClass extends View

Comment: Please visit this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8987632/android-drawing-from-the-main-activity

Comment: Sagar what If I want to use line, circle and other vector graphics on same view,because the one you suggested provides different View for different operation?

Comment: You can create multiple views for it and its better way.

Comment: well I want to create like Microsoft  Paint, where all tools are available in toolbox  , but the above solution creates different view ,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89263/discussion-between-alexander-zaldostanov-and-sagar-zala).